# ASP.NET post JSON data to HTTP API with an authentication header

Tags: c#, json, authentication, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I have C# code to send JSON data to a [web API](https://cloudsigma-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/general.html#authentication) but I keep getting a 401 (Unauthorized) response. The code below should correctly make a POST request according to [this function](https://cloudsigma-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/servers.html#creating), am I right? I have also tried small variations with the same result.

This is the code that makes the request:

```
public async Task Create()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://zrh.cloudsigma.com/api/2.0/");
        var testVM = new CS_VM("test");
        var auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "mail@mail.com", "password");
        var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(auth));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoded);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("servers", testVM);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var a = "ok";
        }
        else
        {
            var a = "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the class that is sent as JSON:

```
public class CS_VM
{
    public CS_VM(string type)
    {
        if ("test" == type)
        {
            cpu = 1000;
            mem = 536870912;
            name = "testServer";
            vcn_password = "testserver";
        }
    }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cpu { get; set; }
    public int cores { get; set; }
    public int mem { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Owner owner { get; set; }
    public Uri resource_uri { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public string vcn_password { get; set; }
}
```

Request headers:

```
Authorization: Basic bWFpbEBtYWlsLmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

And the response headers:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
X-REQUEST-ID: 2584e232-5bb2-48c0-a307-67e6c03258c0
Date: Sun, 19 Jul 2015 21:39:21 GMT
Server: cloudflare-nginx
WWW-Authenticate: Digest nonce="1437341961.55:6967:0fd0a6b2dcde8f45a5ae288c3b73ee12", realm="users", algorithm="MD5",opaque="b228739d1711b0ff025703aea82ee2a208faaaa7", qop="auth", stale="false", Basic Realm="users"
CF-RAY: 2089941a6935168e-ARN
```

Comment: a 401 usually means authentication - my guess is your username/password are getting rejected.  Try sharing the whole response header, see if there's more specific details there.

Comment: Can you inspect the outgoing request to ensure that the header is being sent correctly?

Comment: @Whymarrh I added them to the question. This is what I could get debugging the `client` object just before sending it

Comment: Did you try your code with only get method. https://cloudsigma-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/servers.html#listing. Normally doing a get is simpler than post.

Comment: the api specifies a post https://cloudsigma-docs.readthedocs.org/en/2.11/servers.html#creating

Comment: If it is a digest authentication, the documentation said, it's normal: The values for realm, nonce, and qop are given in the challenge header WWW-Authenticate. The client has to provide the username, password, cnonce, and nc. cnonce or client nonce is a random value generated by the client and nc or nonce counter is a hexadecimal counter which should be incremented with each subsequent request.  

Somehow it's considered digest.

Comment: @ntohl I'm not completely following you. What does that imply?

Comment: I think the authentication is considered digest (don't know why). In the response, You will get 401 with some essential information, that enables You to build a new autherization header. Using the response You got. `nonce="1437341961.55:6967:0fd0a6b2dcde8f45a5ae288c3b73ee12"` and `realm` and `qop`. It seems the 401 response is a challenge, and You have to answer with the given params included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `WWW-Authenticate: Digest nonce="1437341...` it's seems so, that is a digest authentication. You should build a new authorization header from the response You got. Use the methods, that You linked about the [web API](https://cloudsigma-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/general.html#authentication), and use the `Digest Access Authentication` part. the `nonce`, `realm`, `qop` variables are given in the first 401 response.